# Can't use startAt option on keys with special characters in firebase

Tags: rest, firebase, url-parameters

I have a firebase dataset with URLs as keys, such as in this example:

```
{
  "urls" : {
    "http%3A%2F%2Flincoln%2Emetacannon%2Enet%2F2005%2F10%2Ffashion-of-gods%2Easpx" : true,
    "http%3A%2F%2Flincoln%2Emetacannon%2Enet%2F2005%2F10%2Fgod-is-dead-again%%2Easpx" : true,
    "http%3A%2F%2Flincoln%2Emetacannon%2Enet%2F2005%2F10%2Fzugos%2Easpx" : true,
    "http%3A%2F%2Flincoln%ZZmetacannon%ZZnet%2F2005%2F11%2Fgods-creature%ZZaspx" : true
  }
}
```

Using the REST API, when I try to specify a startAt string that includes some kind of special character like %, it stops working. For example, the following query works fine:

```
https://fb-query-tester.firebaseio.com/urls.json?orderBy="$key"&startAt="http"
```

And returns the whole dataset:

```
{
    "http%3A%2F%2Flincoln%2Emetacannon%2Enet%2F2005%2F10%2Ffashion-of-gods%2Easpx": true,
    "http%3A%2F%2Flincoln%2Emetacannon%2Enet%2F2005%2F10%2Fgod-is-dead-again%%2Easpx": true,
    "http%3A%2F%2Flincoln%2Emetacannon%2Enet%2F2005%2F10%2Fzugos%2Easpx": true,
    "http%3A%2F%2Flincoln%ZZmetacannon%ZZnet%2F2005%2F11%2Fgods-creature%ZZaspx": true
}
```

But when I try:

```
https://fb-query-tester.firebaseio.com/urls.json?orderBy="$key"&startAt="http%3A"
```

It returns an empty set:

```
{}
```

I thought maybe I needed to urlencode the query parameter, so I tried:

```
https://fb-query-tester.firebaseio.com/urls.json?orderBy="$key"&startAt="http%253A"
```

But it still returned nothing. I'm not sure what to do at this point. Please help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use url encoded string in Firebase REST Query using startAT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30994506/how-to-use-url-encoded-string-in-firebase-rest-query-using-startat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can use double-percents to encode a percent. But you have to URL-encode them, so instead of using `%%` in place of each `%`, you would use `%25%25`.

So for your example, you could start at the second entry using this URL:

`https://fb-query-tester.firebaseio.com/urls.json?orderBy="$key"&startAt="http%25%253A%25%252F%25%252Flincoln%25%252Emetacannon%25%252Enet%25%252F2005%25%252F10%25%252Fgod-is-dead-again%25%25%25%252Easpx"`